# Using a project from Source control in a different computer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, github, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that was completed on one system and saved to GitHub. Now I have downloaded the projected as a ZIP file from Github and I am trying to execute it. As there is no local database on my system, how should I create the database again without starting up with a new project and copying the code?

I do not want to create the SQL table manually when it can be scaffolded using MVC. AFAIK, when there is no existing database with the name of the database, the database is created and the tables are created. But no table or database is created.

It throws the following exception

> An underlying operation failed an Open

**Update**

I could remove the above exception to get a new exception

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

**More info on the Project**

The project is using Windows Authentication. And the calls to every page in the project is validated before the page is viewed. As I have no table called Users in the database, I get an exception `The underlying operation failed an Open`. I tried to call the Create User method, and create a user with my current credentials, but I am unable to save changes to the database.

Comment: Does the project use EntityFramework?

Comment: Yes. Sorrry, I missed to mention in the question

Comment: I take it you have an instance of SQL Server running - Have you set the connection string in the project to point to this instance?

Comment: i do not have a .mdf file that is same as the model i created. I want it be created as if the project is being executed for the first time

Comment: MDF? So you're using MS Access as the database? You need to add these tags to the question.

Comment: No. I am using Sql Server Express. But the file extension was .mdf when I had the project running in the system that I worked with. I have added more details on the project

Answer (score 0):

1. First in web.config find connection string and change Data Source
   value to your SqlServer address, we assume you use SSMS in your
   windows,

some thing like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

2. Socond open package manager console from View and then write

> Add-Migration InitialCreate

after executing this command, write

> update-database

Comment: in no place i was able to add the codes to ` CreateDatabase`. I have tried adding it in the Context class as well. You ave not mentioned in the answer what is `TestModel`.

Comment: In the solution which you get, exist a file with .edmx format(as you said in comment which the solution has been used entity framework), TestModel is name of that edmx file.

Comment: i am using entity framework. but i cant find any file .emdx file. I am using code first. i have a class which is the dataxontext. I tried to create database using that context, but it throws an exception

Comment: I update my answer with code first, I thought your project was DB-first.